# In k8s yaml files, how to use environment variable in containers

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, yaml

For example, I made a spark:2.4.3 docker image, and I set an ENV SPARK_HOME in the Dockerfile.

When I used `SPARK_HOME` in the yaml file (see code below), I got an error:

> ${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-master.sh: no such file or directory

```
# ...
containers:
  - name: spark-master
    image: spark:2.4.3
    command: 
      - ${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-master.sh
      - --host 0.0.0.0
      - --port $(SPARK_MASTER_PORT) 
      - --webui-port $(SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT)
      - "&&"
      - tail -f $(SPARK_HOME)/logs/*
    env:
      - name: SPARK_MASTER_PORT
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: spark-config
            key: spark_master_port
      - name: SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: spark-config
            key: spark_master_webui_port
# ...
```

Does it mean that I have to use absolute path?

Is there any way to use environment variables in a Kubernetes YAML file?

Comment: The only form of variable expansion that works in a pod spec is `$(VARIABLE_NAME)`; in the first line of your `command:`, the curly braces are not recognized.

Comment: @DavidMaze some guys use curly braces in their spec, e.g., https://github.com/Angatar/mysql-s3-backup/blob/master/s3-dump-cronjob.yaml#L20. Why they do that?

Comment: That specific line is an argument to `sh -c`, and so the main container process is a shell that expands it.  Kubernetes on its own doesn't do anything with that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work that way.

When you define a `ENV` in the Dockerfile, you are declaring the variable for use **inside** the container.

When you set a variable in the `.yaml` file, such variable is meant to be defined at the host level.

If you need to use an environment variable to run your program, use a bash script as entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/bash
${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-master.sh \
--host 0.0.0.0
--port $(SPARK_MASTER_PORT) \
--webui-port $(SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT) \ 
&& tail -f $(SPARK_HOME)/logs/*
```

As this bash script is executed inside the container, it will make use of those environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config,
`$(VAR)` (round braces, as David Maze writes) work for `args`. My try showed it is also replaced in `command`.